# GITkit causing linker errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, google-identity-toolkit

I have written an application that uses Google Identity Toolkit login, and it was working well until I updated to the latest version of Xcode and began developing for iOS 9. I had to install GITkit using Cocoapods, which seems to have been successful, but now upon compiling I get the following errors when I reference certain built-in classes. Also, I had to change my import statements from `#import <GITkit/GITkit.h>` to `#import "GITkit.h"`.

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GITClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in H2LoginViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in H2AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GITIDToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in H2LoginViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GITInterfaceManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in H2LoginViewController.o
  "_kGITProviderFacebook", referenced from:
      -[H2AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in H2AppDelegate.o
  "_kGITProviderGoogle", referenced from:
      -[H2AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in H2AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try going through the [CocoaPods troubleshooting page](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html)? Pay extra attention to the section "If Xcode can’t find the headers of the dependencies".

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, though I ended up just creating an entirely new project and following the CocoaPods installation and configuration instructions more carefully.